# Select the first n smallest files from a folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a directory with many files, roughly 50k. I would like to select the **n** smallest files.

```
import os

def main():
listfile = os.listdir("../../folder")
for singlefile in listfile:
    print singlefile
```

with this code, unfortunatly, I will select them all.

Comment: what do you mean by "smaller dimension"?

Comment: smaller size of file. @MSeifert

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I already thought so but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.getsize`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) to get the filesize and then just `sort` your files by it (`heapq.nsmallest` is generally preferred but already covered in another answer, so I'll show an alternative):

```
import os

directory = "../../folder"
n = 10

files = os.listdir(directory)
files_sorted_by_size = sorted(files, key=lambda filename: os.path.getsize(os.path.join(directory, filename)))  
nsmallest_files = files_sorted_by_size[:n] 
print(nsmallest_files)
```

In one line:

```
sorted(os.listdir(directory), key=lambda filename: os.path.getsize(os.path.join(directory, filename)))[:n]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
 # The folder containing files.
 directory = ""../../folder""

 # Get all files.
 list = os.listdir(directory)

 # Loop and add files to list.
 pairs = []
 for file in list:

   # Use join to get full file path.
   location = os.path.join(directory, file)

   # Get size and add to list of tuples.
   size = os.path.getsize(location)
   pairs.append((size, file))

   # Sort list of tuples by the first element, size.
   pairs.sort(key=lambda s: s[0])

 # Display pairs.
 for pair in pairs:
  print(pair[1])
```

Comment: Does this code select the first 10 files with size, in KB, less?

Comment: This will indeed select first 10 files. Do you also want to sort by file size? In the question you did not specify.

Comment: Yes,it work. But i need only the name of file in list.

Comment: @hackkato - cool then only display index of name. Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) to get a file's size. In conjuction with [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest), you can easily find the smallest files:

```
from os import listdir
from os import stat
from heapq import nsmallest

n = 10
listfile = listdir("../../folder")
smallest = nsmallest(n, listfile, lambda x : stat(x).st_size)
```

Comment: @hackkato This works fine for me. Care to share what error you're getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "prova.py", line 8, in main
    smallest = nsmallest(n, listfile, lambda x : stat(x).st_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/heapq.py", line 432, in nsmallest
    result = _nsmallest(n, it)
  File "prova.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    smallest = nsmallest(n, listfile, lambda x : stat(x).st_size)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'classes.apk.txt'

Comment: No need for the `lambda` here anyway... just pass it `os.path.getsize`...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above good solutions, here's my 25 cents. you may use `os.walk, os.stat & sorted` functions to get n smallest files from the directory. It can also be extended to recursive directories.

```
import os


def get_n_smallest_files(directory, n):
    file_map = {}
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
       for file_path in [root + file for file in files]:
           file_map[file_path] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
    return sorted(file_map.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[:n]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory = "/path/to/directory/"
    small_files_limit = 10
    print get_n_smallest_files(directory, small_files_limit)
```